# fopen strip into php variables

Tags: php, html, parsing, strip

I'm trying to extract the following in php, but my regex or egreg is out of place and i got really confused. Please help me put these to two variables:

```
  <a onmouseover="dgsa.sm(this)" onmouseout="dgsa.hm();" href="http://www.cnn.com/testpage.html#page_mostview">test titles</a>
```

I want the variable:

```
$url="http://www.cnn.com/testpage.html#page_mostview";
$title="test titles";
```

Any kind of help on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use a `DOMDocument` to parse the HTML and extract the values from there instead.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/374601

Comment: @erty The <center> cannot hold it is too late! :O

Comment: @minitech I tried looking thru it but I can't seem to comprehend. All this is very new to me. I have quite a few of the lines to strip so I would like to do a loop for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have in one big string:

```
<?php
$str = '<a href="ABC.jpg">Hello</a>  <a href="DEF.jpg">Bye</a>';
$expr = '/<a[^>]*? href=\"(?<url>[^\"]+)\"[^>]*?>(?<text>.*?)<\/a>/';
echo preg_match_all($expr, $str, $amatches);
echo '<br><br>';
print_r($amatches);
?>
```

You can also use:

```
preg_match_all($expr, $str, $amatches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

Which may suit better (I ofen prefer this approach)

If you have in spearate strings and handle in a loop, use preg_match instead. Tis will only return the first, and you loop.

---

Edit: here it is with your example, as requested.

```
<?php

$str = '<a onmouseover="dgsa.sm(this)" onmouseout="dgsa.hm();" href="http://www.cnn.com/testpage.html#page_mostview">test titles</a>';

$expr = '/<a[^>]*? href=\"(?<url>[^\"]+)\"[^>]*?>(?<text>.*?)<\/a>/';

echo preg_match_all($expr, $str, $amatches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

echo '<br><br>';

print_r($amatches);

?>
```

Comment: I have been trying the past few hours and I can't seem to get it to do what I want. Can you please help revised your answer with my examples? It will definitely help me learn.

Comment: No - that's not giving troubles. I've simply pasted in your string, as requested. Tested and works a treat. So check what you're copying / pasting.